# Create a model method if association is not set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have a `Post` model that `belongs_to :author`. If the author is set on the post during creation, `post.author` returns the author. However, if the author is not set on the post, I want to still return a default author upon calling `post.author`. I have the following:

```
class Post
  belongs_to :author

  def author
    begin
      Author.find(read_attribute("author_id"))
    rescue
      Author.default_author
    end
  end
end
```

My question is whether it is ok to override the association method `author`. Will this cause any internal processing on the association, etc. to get bypassed? Is there a better way to do this? For example, should I use something like `method_missing` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#app/models/post.rb
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   before_create :set_author, unless: Proc.new {|post| post.author.present? }

   private

   def set_author
      self.author_id = "2"
   end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd set it `before_validation` if it's blank

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author

  before_validation :set_author
  validates :author, :presence => true

  def set_author
    self.author = Author.default if author.blank?
  end

end
```

Comment: Thanks, the way I phrased the question, you are right. However, in my actual case, the default_author is a function of the post itself. So, some times, I cannot get the default_author before the post is created.

Comment: Can you create or find the default author based on the params of the post?  Or do you need it to be in the db for some reason?

Answer (score 0):

In your particular case, I **would not recommend**

> overriding the association method author

with the same name as the column in the database because if you think of another developer coming behind you, it wouldn't be obvious to them that calling the author attribute on post doesn't just return the data for the author column, but it in fact returns the default author if it doesn't exist.

So for that reason i would say you need to make a new method called something like `author_or_default_author` so it's hopefully obvious what that method returns

Also, overriding that column name in your model will in fact run that code when you're just simply trying to create an Author record. Whether that would be desirable or not it definitely wouldn't be blatantly obvious to another developer

You might consider doing something like this instead

```
class Post
  belongs_to :author

  def author_or_default_author
    Author.where(id: author_id).present? || Author.default_author
  end
end
```

and calling it with

```
post.author_or_default_author
```

One benefit of using .where in my example above is that you don't have to deal with `activerecord not found` type of error that would happen if you tried Author.find(1234) when 1234 wasn't a valid author id. So you can get rid of the `begin and rescue` that you were using